# Unknown class <DrawerClickableItem>"

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

i want to add items to NavigationDrawer but i get this "Unknown class " errors instead.

i tried defining a Class "DrawerClickableItem" but it wouldn't work instead i get errors. i have tried several options that seem to work but "DrawerClickableItem" always gives an error. the codes are below.

python code

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivymd.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

Window.size = [320, 600]


class ShopApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        global screen_manager

        screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file('home.kv'))
        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file('Sign_up.kv'))

        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file('login.kv'))

        return screen_manager


ShopApp().run()
```

kv file

```
MDScreen:
    name: 'home'
    md_bg_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    background_normal: ''

    MDNavigationLayout:
        ScreenManager:
            Screen:
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    MDTopAppBar:
                        md_bg_color: [0, 0, 0, 1]
                        elevation: 2.5
                        title: "Home"
                        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]

                    Widget:


        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
            size_hint: .3, .9
            radius: (0, 30, 30, 0)
            md_bg_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            pos_hint: {'y': .1}
            scrim_color: 0, 0, 0, 0

            MDNavigationDrawerMenu:

                MDNavigationDrawerHeader:
                    title: "Header title"
                    title_color: "#4a4939"
                    text: "Header text"
                    spacing: "4dp"
                    padding: "12dp", 0, 0, "56dp"

                MDNavigationDrawerLabel:
                    text: "Mail"

                DrawerClickableItem:
                    icon: "gmail"
                    right_text: "+99"
                    text_right_color: "#4a4939"
                    text: "Inbox"

                DrawerClickableItem:
                    icon: "send"
                    text: "Outbox"

                MDNavigationDrawerDivider:

                MDNavigationDrawerLabel:
                    text: "Labels"

                DrawerLabelItem:
                    icon: "information-outline"
```

Answer (score 0):

the new class needs to be defined and inherit one that exists.

this can be done in a .kv file that you load with Builder.loadfile("filename.kv") or put this code in a .kv file that you already have.  properties can be defined such as the size hint that I placed as an example.

```
<DrawerClickableItem@MDNavigationDrawer>:
    size_hint_x: 5
```

Comment: i defined the class <DrawerClickableItem@MDNavigationDrawer>:
and <ExtendedButton@MDNavigationDrawer>:. its runs without errors but i only get the Menu icon in the navigationlayout. The clickable items are not visible.